# some error will be printed in consoled when i export highcharts

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I want to export highcharts.

I found that `chart.exportChart` can help me.

it can export a static chart.

But if i use it to export a dynamic chart, a image will be exported and
**"*highcharts.js:285 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined*"**   will be printed in console.

who can tell me why?

here is an experiment of exporting a dynamic chart:http://jsfiddle.net/u02amghs/

if you click "export chart" , error message will be printed in console.

here is an experiment of exporting a static chart:http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/chart-exportchart-filename/

Comment: This seems to be an issue with any dynamic chart. if you set `exporting: { enabled: true}` in this demo, you get the same error: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/dynamic-update/. You may want to post this question on their support forum as well: http://forum.highcharts.com/

Comment: Might be relevant: I removed the setInterval and added a button to add point to the serie. Now it seems like I can't reproduce the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/hvoLjouj/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you want to add points to the exported chart. When exporting chart, new chart is generated (**including** `chart.events.load` callback), exported and then destroyed. `setInterval` is not cleared and that's why you see that error. And to answer your question, don't add `setInterval` when chart should be exported:

```
chart: {
  events: {
    load: function() {

      if (!this.options.chart.forExport) {
        // set up the updating of the chart each second
        var series = this.series[0];
        setInterval(function() {
          var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
            y = Math.random();
          series.addPoint(['Jan', y], true, true);
        }, 1000);
      }
    }
  }
},
```

`options.chart.forExport` is inner property, set only when exporting chart.

Comment: Thank you. It really sloves this problem.